# Administrator notification on user registration

Tags: emails

Administrator is not notified when a user registers on my D7 site, while the registrants do receive a message. On the D6 version of the site it worked. Here's the setup:

- Drupal 7.10
- User registration is upon admin approval.
- Contact users works.

I can't find a flag anywhere to turn on notification to administrator. Google search and search on this site has not turned up a solution. Is this capability in core, how do I turn it on. Do I have to use additional module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, go to `/admin/config/system/actions`. In the section "Create an advanced action", choose "send an email" and click on "create". It takes you to a page where you need to enter a recipients email address, (enter the Administrator's email address here), subject and message. Click Save.

Second, go to `/admin/modules` and enable the Trigger module.

Third, go to `/admin/structure/trigger/user`. In the Section "Trigger: After creating a new user account" Choose "Send e-mail" in the select box. Click Assign.

Example Message:

```
A user has created an account.

Details:
 - Username: [user:name]
 - Email: [user:mail]
 - Time: [user:created:long]

Activate their account by going here: [user:edit-url]
```

Comment: aerozeppelin, Thanks for your instructions. Perfect. Configured and tested; works great. For me, it was also a small tutorial on actions and triggers; gave me ideas. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @MPD, Thanks for the reminder. I am a StackExchange newbie.

Comment: It is required that you first enable the module Trigger at admin/modules

Comment: @aerozeppelin Maybe mention the need to enabled the `Trigger` module in your answer. I also stumbled across this problem, like batigolix.

Comment: How can this functionality be used to set multiple recipients ?

Answer (score 11):

Although this is an old question, I just found it in a search, and found that the suggested approach, though excellent, does not work with Tokens.

If you want the administrator to be sent an email that contains some or all of the fields that you have attached to your user account: eg something like:

[account:field-contact-name] has created an account.
Details submitted: [account:field-business-name]

Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module which offers a nice simple tokenised email approach.

Once you have installed Rules,  from /admin/config/workflow/rules, add a new rule.

1) Add an event : After saving a new user account

2) Add an action: Send Mail

3) In the message body, choose your tokens from the Replacement Patterns dropdown and save your new Rule.

4) test, and rejoice at how lovely Rules is.

Answer (score 2):

User registration **workflow** (*pending email to "site admin" and "user" --> approve by "site admin" then confirmation email to the user*)  is a default (core) system of drupal.

From `Admin > Configuration > People > Account Settings` page, set Red-marked option of the attached image.

[image]

Note:
You can set email content (message) in the **E-mail** section from bottom of the same account setting page.

[image]