# User Registration to provide password on registration pg administrator approval and verification email

Tags: users

[I tried looking for similar answers, I just got this: Administrator notification on user registration

For user registration I want:
1) Password and Confirm Password field on Registration page
2) Admin approval for account creation
3) Verification Email to be sent to the user

```
* For `Who can register accounts?` the setting says : `Visitors, but administrator approval is required`.
* I've installed the package "User registration password" to have password on registration page as well as getting a verification email sent
```

`Problem`: If I don't enable "Admin Approval" registration works fine. The user account is created immediately and it gets a verification email with a link which can be used to confirm the account.

If I enable `Visitors, but administrator approval is required`nothing works. User account is created, but it doesn't get a mail, admin doesn't get a mail and account is not activated.

Am I supposed to create a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the settings you are currently using, the user creating the account should receive an e-mail. On the `admin/config/people/accounts` page, near the bottom, look for the vertical tab labelled "Welcome (awaiting approval)". This is the e-mail the user should receive while waiting for the account to receive administrator approval. Check the Recent log messages page (`admin/reports/dblog`) to see if the e-mail is being sent by Drupal. If it is, check the spam filter on the e-mail account receiving the e-mail.

You will need to set up a trigger so that administrators receive e-mails when new accounts are created. I believe that the superuser account (the user created when installing Drupal) should automatically receive e-mails about new accounts. To notify additional e-mail addresses when accounts are created, see the directions listed at [Administrator notification on user registration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/administrator-notification-on-user-registration). You'll need to enable the Trigger module if it's not already enabled. If you want to e-mail all users having a certain role when an account is created (for example, e-mail all administrators), check out the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

I would also look into the [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module. This module also allows the user to enter their password on account creation, but has several other great options. It allows you to set an additional role applied to users when they first create the account but before they verify the account. With this role, you can allow users to create an account and log in immediately, but not perform actions until they verify the account. The LoginToboggan module also allows users to log in using their e-mail address, and display two e-mail address fields on the registration page. I would recommend looking into this module as a replacement for the "User registration password" module you're currently using.

Comment: Could you let me know if this problem was ever fully resolved? I am experiencing the same problem with no emails being sent

Comment: @CardiffSteve, are you not getting any e-mails from your Drupal installation? There are many reasons why e-mails won't be sent from a server. Test and see if you get any e-mails by using the `/user/password` page to send yourself a password reset email. If it doesn't come through, try the steps at [Drupal not Sending Email? Let's Debug it!](http://www.drupalconnect.com/blog/articles/drupal-not-sending-email-lets-debug-it)

Comment: I get emails using just Drupal core, and I have set up an email trigger as described above which works, it just doesn't send emails relating to what User Registration Password is meant to do i.e. send email to administrator and user. I have raised another question here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189521/no-emails-being-sent-when-using-user-registration-password-set-up