# No emails being sent when using User Registration Password set up

Tags: 7, users

When a new user registers with my website it displays "Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.
In the meantime, a welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address."

However, no email is sent from the site at all.

I have my settings so that approval is required from the administrator before the user can be activated. Also, they set their password up on the registration screen.

Im using v1.4 of the **[User Registration Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) module**, and Drupal 7.41

Could someone let me know why no emails go to the administrator or the users ? Emails were being sent without the module installed, but I really want users to set their password up front.

[image]

Comment: maybe the problem not come from Drupal

Comment: Is any mail sent in other situations? Maybe problem is more general?

Comment: Ive set up a trigger to send an email when a user is created, and that works fine. so at least I have a notification and I know my emails work fine. My emails work fine just using drupal core without the User Registration Password.

Comment: Maybe try using the dev version of the module.

Comment: Have a look at the issue queue for the module: https://www.drupal.org/node/2152925 There seems to be a patch

Comment: i have now installed the dev version, and it works perfectly when 'who can register accounts' = 'visitors', but when i select 'Visitors, but administrator approval is required' no emails are sent. It creates the account as blocked. I get an email because I have a trigger set when a user is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all works perfectly now, i needed to use an email address that belongs to my domain i.e. anything@mydomain.co.uk otherwise it gets blocked, therefore use this email in Configuration/Site Information and also in the Trigger rule I created to alert me when a new user is created. Thank you for guiding me towards using the Dev version.